# Non-linear (?) differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm walking through differential equations on my own, but I found example which make me stop for some time.

$$(t^{2} - y^{2}) \cdot y' = 2ty$$
Any help would be appreciated - is this any special method for particular kind of square equations?

Cheers!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try homogeneous DE since the coefficient degrees on both sides match. That is, substitute $y=tu$,
$$
y'=tu'+u=\frac{2u}{1-u^2}
$$ 
Next use separation of variables.

Comment: That's right, thanks!